# Cypher shell not installable (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

On Ubuntu 16.04, I've added the package repo for Neo4j (http://debian.neo4j.org/), but when I try to do `sudo apt-get upgrade neo4j` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 neo4j : Depends: cypher-shell but it is not installable
E: Broken packages
```

I've tried to find the package repo where `cypher-shell` resides, but to no avail. Where is it?

Comment: It seems as if they released a new version today that is missing a dependency, or have yet to update their install documentation.

I was able to install 3.0.9 successfully with: `sudo apt-get install -y neo4j=3.0.9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this. We have now released cypher-shell to the repo and Neo4j 3.1.4 installs successfully.

Comment: Not for me; I'm attempting to install using the instructions on debian.neo4j.org but I am told that the following unmet dependencies can't be installed: openjdk-8-jre-headless, java8-runtime-headless, cypher-shell

Comment: @Sinfieldd What is your OS? There is a note on http://debian.neo4j.org/ about earlier versions of Debian and Ubuntu needing Java 8 installed manually (and more details at http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/linux/debian/).

Comment: It's Debian Jessie, but I got it sorted in the end by installing Java 8 manually 